# Nested group summary statistics in reframe function of dplyr in R

Tags: r, dplyr

Assume that I have `df` like this:

```
df <- tribble(
  ~Country, ~Gender, ~var,
  "Bangladesh", "F", 2.5,
  "Bangladesh", "M", 4.5,
  "Bangladesh", "M", 4.1,
  "US", "F", 1.7,
  "US", "F", 2.7,
  "US", "M", 3.5,
)
```

We can do following task easily and separately:
one for grouping based on `Country` and `Gender`

```
df %>% 
  group_by(Country, Gender) %>%
  reframe(
    n = n(),
    meanVar = mean(var))
```

and the other if we like to know the overall values in each country:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(Country) %>%
  reframe(
    n = n(),
    meanVar = mean(var))
```

but I was wondering whether we could have an output in which we have three rows of summary statistics for each country: `F`, `M` and `All` for all female and male in each country.

Comment: In a recent [blog post](https://tim-tiefenbach.de/post/2023-dplyr-many-models/) I cover this and other issues when dealing with nested `data.frame`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `bind_rows()` and change  `Gender` to `"All"` first, then group by `Country` and `Gender`:

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(Gender = "All") %>% 
  bind_rows(., df) %>% 
  group_by(Country, Gender) %>% 
  summarise(n = n(),
            meanVar = mean(var))

#> # A tibble: 6 × 4
#> # Groups:   Country [2]
#>   Country    Gender     n meanVar
#>   <chr>      <chr>  <int>   <dbl>
#> 1 Bangladesh All        3    3.7 
#> 2 Bangladesh F          1    2.5 
#> 3 Bangladesh M          2    4.3 
#> 4 US         All        3    2.63
#> 5 US         F          2    2.2 
#> 6 US         M          1    3.5
```

Data from OP

```
df <- tribble(
  ~Country, ~Gender, ~var,
  "Bangladesh", "F", 2.5,
  "Bangladesh", "M", 4.5,
  "Bangladesh", "M", 4.1,
  "US", "F", 1.7,
  "US", "F", 2.7,
  "US", "M", 3.5,
)
```

<sup>Created on 2023-04-02 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Nice hack. I often have similar use cases and it never occurred to me that the easiest way would be to add the „total“ to the data frame before grouping.

Comment: It’s a nice trick, but with a lot of groups I actually prefer data-less grids. I have linked a recent blog post in the comments to the OP.