# R: Identifying dublicates across columns within categories

Tags: r, merge, duplicates

My data frame consists of 550 rows with 90 variables. All relevant variables are characters. Each row is unique by a combination of the 4 descriptor variables (Name, Question, Gender, Level), however for each Name-Question combination, there's 6 rows. Across these 6 rows, I need to identify whether any letter_number combination in columns V1 to V86 occurs more than once.

An subset/example of the data would be:

| Name | Question | Gender | Level | V1 | V2 | V3 | V4 | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| George | Question1 | m | 3 | F7 | A1 | H5 |  |  |
| George | Question2 | m | 2 | G8 | B1 | H5 | K7 |  |
| Frederic | Question1 | m | 1 | **K9** | C5 | G9 |  |  |
| Frederic | Question1 | f | 1 | A1 | **K9** |  |  |  |
| Frederic | Question1 | m | 2 | F7 |  |  |  |  |
| Frederic | Question1 | f | 2 | G1 | G2 | B3 | P5 |  |
| Frederic | Question1 | m | 3 | P4 | P9 |  |  |  |
| Frederic | Question1 | f | 3 | K1 | H5 | P6 |  |  |

Where I want to identify that K9 occurs more than once for the Frederic_Question1 combination.

Ideally the output would be pasted as a new column containing the duplicate(s) (e.g. K9) in the original data frame (as these needs to be checked manually in relation to other columns).

I have tried what feels like a million things, including using aggregate, mutate(), unite(), nest(), duplicate(). One idea was/is to first merge the code variables (V1-V86) to a vector or list, one for each Name-Question combination across rows, in order to use duplicate(). However, even merging seems to be problematic (different row length), and I am not even sure this is the best way to go about it.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: One approach is to ```tidyr::pivot_longer``` V1 to V86 and then ```reframe(n=n(),.by=c(Name,Question,value))```. This allows you to filter row with n>=2, which are the duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

To add a little more clarity to @peter861222's comment, you can run:

```
data %>%
  pivot_longer(starts_with("V"), names_to = "v_level") %>%
  reframe(n=n(),.by=c(Name,Question,value), across(c(Gender, Level)))
```

This will summarize the data by `Name`, `Question`, and `value` ("K9", "A1", etc). The `across` statement will leave the `Gender` and `Level` columns as you have them. You can filter this resulting data set with `filter(value == "K9")` to see just the results for "K9"

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! I get the error message: "Error in `pivot_longer()`:
! Names must be unique." I've tried adding a group_by beforehand, but didn't help.

Comment: I think this is because you have a column called `Name` and `pivot_longer` automatically uses a column called `name`. I've fixed this in the code above by adding the `names_to` parameter to name the column `v_level` instead of `name`. The code should work now :)

Comment: Thanks a lot again for your answer! I have now succeeded in making your code string work for me, however it unfortunately doesn't quite give me what I am looking for. First of, I would like the duplicate information to be added to the original data frame as I need to manually check it in relation to information in other non-mentioned columns. It could be as a new column, or inspired by another post here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75912422/nested-group-summary-statistics-in-reframe-function-of-dplyr-in-r), as a row underneath each name_question combination. (More follows...)

Comment: Second, I actually need to do three things: (1) Check for duplicates across the six rows with same Name Question combinations, as mentioned above, (2) compare all codes in male/female subsets of this with a list (vector) of valid codes (that is, compare across three rows with same Name Question Gender combination TO a "external" list), in order to identify (A) invalid codes used, and (B) valid codes not used.  (More follows...)

Comment: Based on this, I am thinking that the way to go perhaps is to create a vector for (i) all codes (V1:V86) across the 6 rows with same Name Question combination, (ii) another vector as (i) but only Gender=male, (iii) as (ii) but Gender=female. With vectors, I should then be able to use functions "x[duplicated(x)]" and "settdiff()" to get listed the codes answering my tasks 1-3. This I then would like reported in the original dataframe (or a copy thereof) in new rows or columns.

Comment: I am experimenting around with code like the below, but it is quite far from working: 'data_all%>%
  mutate(Question = "All") %>% 
  bind_rows(., data_all) %>% 
  group_by(ID,Question) %>%
  select(V1:V86)%>% 
  as.vector()%>% 
  duplicated()'. Thanks a lot in advance for any further help! :)